# Получить доступ на сервис, который запрещен для российских пользователей

Tags: vps, vpn

Мне нужно получить доступ на финтех сервис, работа в котором запрещена для пользователей из России. Работа с ним как в браузере, так и в клиенте.

Я установил VPS с доступом из Нидерландов, но они все равно видят, что я из России. С VPN та же ситуация. Более того, даже гугл распознает мое местоположение - меня переадресовывает на google.nl, но предлагают русский язык.

Вопрос: как поступить, чтобы максимально скрыть мое местоположение? Использовать удаленный рабочий стол или некие тоннели? Я с ними никогда не работал.

Comment: ничто не выдавало штирлица, ни user-agent, ни предпочитаемый язык, ни файлы cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать тор браузер см. тут: https://www.torproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

Используй прокси , можешь попытать удачу с мак-адресом.
Пользуйся виртуальной машиной с Tails OS , а также баузером Linken Sphere